# jqgrid by using [WebMethod] inside aspx file

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid for my project.
So far, jqgrid is ok while I'm using with `ahsx` file
But when I try to use [WebMethod] in `aspx` file, I get error `500`.
Here is my jqgrid setting

```
            $(document).ready(function () {  
            $("#JQGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'Testing.aspx/LoadMachineCapacity',
                mtype: 'POST',
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                datatype: "json", 
                postData: {}, 
                height: 100,
                autowidth: true, 
                loadtext: "Loading...", 
                colModel: [
                    {
                        name: 'MACHINEID',
                        index: 'MACHINEID',
                        label: 'Machine ID',
                        sortable: false,
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ISACTIVE',
                        index: 'ISACTIVE',
                        label: 'IS ACTIVE',
                        sortable: false,
                        editable: true
                    }], 
                loadonce: true,
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                multiselect: false, 
                caption: 'Machines',  
                pager: '#JQGridPager', 
                pgbuttons: true, rowNum: 10, rowList: [10, 20, 30], 
                rownumbers: true,
                viewrecords: true
                , cellEdit: true
                , afterEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                    alert(value);
                },
                loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                        'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
                        'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '\n' +
                        'errorDesc.: ' + jqXHR.responseText); 
                }
            });
            $("#JQGrid").navGrid('#JQGridPager',
                { view: false, edit: false, search: true, add: false, del: false, refresh: true }
            ); 
        });
```

and here is my server-side code

```
  [WebMethod] 
public static string LoadMachineCapacity(string pageIndex)
{
    string Result = "";

    try
    {
        string strOracleCnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PKERP"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection oracleConn = new OracleConnection(strOracleCnnString);


        string strSQL = " SELECT *  " +
                        " FROM  T_CT_MCCP  " ;

        OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, oracleConn);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);


        Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable, Formatting.Indented);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.Message, Formatting.Indented);
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Thank in advance.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

There are a parameter at `Webmethod`.

However, your jqGrid setting not config at `postData`.

Change to  postData: {pageIndex: "blabla"}.